# Isn't three-dimensional really three-directional?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

This occured to me while writing a mathematics/physics library. Given a 3d shape such as a cube, since it provides a simple demonstration, you have three commonly used measures: length, width, and height. All three are measured as distance, the same dimension. If it were to really be three dimensional, wouldn't we be considering something like distance, time, and mass? Furthermore, given a flat drawing such as a square, how can we really say it is 2d, as it could just be a surface draught (as is commonly done in engineering: several faces, and then an isometric).

Or am I completely off, and why?

Comment: The volume of that cube would be measured in distance$^3$.  Also, in math, "dimension" doesn't generally mean what unit you measure stuff in (physicists care about that, but mathematicians usually deal with *pure* numbers).  It means roughly how many components you need to specify a point.

Comment: Ah, so it's an oh-so-lovely difference in definition. Gotta love that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a three-dimensional vector space has "directions" in the sense that a vector is directional (a point often made in introductory physics materials to delineate "velocity" from "speed" by saying the former has "direction" that the latter lacks).

However the "three" part of the qualification needs clarification.  How many directions are there in three-dimensonal space?  The most likely conclusion that a student would draw is that there are infinitely many different directions, left, right, up, down, sideways...!

So we need some mathematical formalism to explain why "three" is special in numbering directions, and this gets to the issue of *linear independence*.  In a more specialized setting (Euclidean geometry) one might use the notion of two directions being *at right angles* (orthogonal), but strictly speaking this notion of an angle between two vectors is something that comes not with abstract vector spaces but rather with inner product spaces, an extended definition.

In any case in the setting of a simple vector space we can define *three-dimensional* quite precisely by saying there exists a *basis* of three vectors, a basis being a set of linearly independent vectors that span the vector space.  Perhaps you could set a goal of reworking this formalism in a perferred terminology of *directions*, but I'm not aware of any true alternative approach to how we count the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Except for the part about reusing a word with a somewhat different definition in an incredibly closely related field. That's not your fault though, more just a quirk in how fields developed.

In your opinion then, does terminology such as 2-basevector (2bv), 3-basevector (3bv), etc. create less ambiguity than 2-dimensional, 3-dimensional, etc?

Comment: Having exactly one meaning for each word is [an ancient ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xunzi#Rectifying_Names), but as we can better appreciate from a modern perspective, unattainable in colloquial speech.  While we may confidently refer to the *dimensions* of an object or drawing, expecting that to be understood operationally as measurements, the *numbering* of those measurements (distances) is also important.  So for a three-dimensional object we expect three measurements, and for two-dimensional drawings (perhaps of the same objects, projected to a plane) we expect two measurements.

Comment: While the use of a word like dimension to have more than one meaning (even in mathematics per se, see the wiki excerpt for your tag "dimension-theory") risks *ambiguity*, it also helps tie together closely related lines of thought, creating fruitful analogies.

Comment: I suppose my issue with dimensions being measurable parts is that there are, in fact, more measurable parts possible than are being considered. If one takes a cube and skews various parts, still attaining a form with 8-3d-angles, but with varying lengths to each edge, doesn't the dimensionality then rapidly increase? Or is the only concern with measurements of imaginary lines of a 3d-cartesian space (or other space)?

Comment: Measurements are a concern of physicists and engineers. Math is concerned with them only in fairly abstract ways: What are statistical properties of measurement errors?  What "measurements" suffice to characterize something "up to isomorphism"? Etc. I've pointed to a precise definition of *dimension* in vector spaces (and there are other areas, Hausdorff dimension in topology and Krull dimension in ring theory, where the word is reused with a different but still precise definition).  Giving words formal definitions means cutting the chord with their informal uses.